# Add Reminder List programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, eventkit, ekreminder

I'm building an application that interacts with the macOS Reminder App. I'm trying to create a new Reminder list into which I later can import reminders.

This is what I have so far:

```
func setCalendar(_ type: EKEntityType) {

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    let newCalendar = EKCalendar(for: type, eventStore: eventStore)
    newCalendar.title="newcal"
    print("Cal: " + newCalendar.title)

    try? eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)

}
```

However, there is no reminder list being created.

Comment: How are you calling this function? Have you requested access to the reminders? Are capabilities set up correctly in your project?

Comment: Your code ignores errors silently, which is a very bad practice. What do you get if you replace the last line to `do {try eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true);print("success")} catch {print(error)}` ?

Comment: I call the function from a custom importer class using setCalendar(.reminder) from within init. I do request access to reminders and have all capabilities set correctly => I do get the existing reminder lists that I use for a drop down field.

Comment: I added the do {} catch {} => Calendar has no Source... how do I add a source to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have omitted to specify the new calendar's `.source`. You cannot create a calendar of any kind (event or reminder) without doing that.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was missing.